# Why DOM didn't update by setAttribute when using Aframe v0.5.0?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm going to set the **aframe-v0.5.0** `<a-box>` position and color, and it renders correct in the browser, but when I use box.getAtrribute("position"), it returns "undefined", then I found `<a-box>` positon attribute is empty string showing in the DOM(same situation for scale/rotation):

```
<a-box width="1" geometry="" height="1" depth="1" color="#0cf" material="" position="" rotation="" scale="" visible=""></a-box>
```

So I switch back to **aframe-v0.2.0**, and everything works fine!
Can't get any answer from google, is it something changed in aframe-v0.5.0?
Here's my code below, and aframe.js is put in the `<head>`, my script is put in the `<body>`.

```
var body = document.body;
var scene = document.createElement("a-scene");
var camera = document.createElement("a-entity");
    camera.setAttribute("camera", "userHeight: 1.6");
    camera.setAttribute("look-controls", "");
    camera.setAttribute("wasd-controls", "");
var box = document.createElement("a-box");
    box.setAttribute("width", 1);
    box.setAttribute("height", 1);
    box.setAttribute("depth", 1);
    box.setAttribute("color", "#0cf");
    box.setAttribute("position", "0 0 -5");
scene.appendChild(camera);
scene.appendChild(box);
body.appendChild(scene);

console.log( box.getAttribute("position") ) //"undefined"
```

example here:
http://minicg.com/demo/aframe050_test/

Answer (score 2):

https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/introduction/faq.html#why-is-the-html-not-updating-when-i-check-the-browser-inspector

> If you open up your browser’s developer tools, you’ll see that the HTML attribute values are empty.
>
> To improve performance, A-Frame does not update the HTML to save on stringification operations. Use the debug component or .flushToDOM methods if you need to sync to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't noticed this faq before!

Comment: Thanks, that explains a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

im not sure if I'm correct, but in my opinion You try to read the attribute before it's properly placed on the scene. When i added a 2s `setTimeout()` before the `getAttribute()` call, it works fine:
https://codepen.io/gftruj/pen/JJoENb

But waiting 2 seconds before reading attributes is outrageous !!! 
Yep, that's why i'd recommend putting your code inside a registered component. You can add any js code in the init() function, and You should be sure everything is properly loaded.
 For example create manually a `<a-scene myCode>` element, and put your code in

```
    AFRAME.registerComponent('myCode', {
      init: function () {
        //whatever you want, remember that the scope here is not the window, 
        //but the element using this component ( now it'd be the a-scene)
      }
    });
```

Comment: One other note: inside that `init()` function you can call `this.el` to get the current element.

Comment: sure, depends what items You want to access, i thought WaveF wants to manage the whole scene from one component ( hence creating everything in js )

Comment: Thanks, I will try aframe component, just wondering why it acts difference between 0.2.0 and 0.5.0.